# How to explode the values in the array and it as a separate columns by creating it dynamically using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, sql, codeigniter

```
public function addDynFields()
{
    $checkedfileds=$_POST['CheckedFileds'];
    $fields=implode(',',$checkedfileds);
    $dynflds = strtolower($fields);
    $dynclmns = 'add_to'.'_'.$dynflds;
    if($fields == 'Title')
    {
        $this->db->query("ALTER TABLE `pm1asset_dynamic_fields` ADD ".$dynclmns." int(11) NOT NULL");
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->query("ALTER TABLE `pm1asset_dynamic_fields` ADD ".$dynclmns." varchar(255) NOT NULL");
    }
}
```

Here above code is a controller code. Here `$checkedfileds` is a multiple check box values in the array form. Here i want to explode the `$checkedfileds(Array)` values and store it as a separate columns in a table.

If i include `$checkedfileds` in `$this->db->query("ALTER TABLE pm1asset_dynamic_fields ADD ".$checkedfileds." varchar(255) NOT NULL");` it is created as a Array as a column name in a table, suppose if i include `$dynclmns` in `$this->db->query("ALTER TABLE pm1asset_dynamic_fields ADD ".$dynclmns." varchar(255) NOT NULL");` it created as a add_to_title but next column is not created, i don't know why it's not going to create. can any one please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to repair your sql query syntax and modify your codes like this :

```php
$checkedfileds = $_POST['CheckedFileds'];
$qry = "ALTER TABLE `pm1asset_dynamic_fields` ";
foreach ($checkedfileds as $key => $value) {
    $dynflds = strtolower($value);
    $dynclmns = 'add_to' . '_' . $dynflds;
    if ($value == 'Title') {
        $qry .= "ADD COLUMN `" . $dynclmns . "` int(11) NOT NULL";
    } else {
        $qry .= "ADD COLUMN `" . $dynclmns . "` varchar(255) NOT NULL";
    }
    end($checkedfileds);
    // use (;) for the last row, otherwise use (,)
    if ($key === key($checkedfileds)) {
        $qry .= ";";
    } else {
        $qry .= ", ";
    }
}
$this->db->query($qry);
```

This will generate query like below :

```sql
ALTER TABLE `pm1asset_dynamic_fields` 
ADD COLUMN `add_to_title` int(11) NOT NULL,
ADD COLUMN `add_to_col2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
ADD COLUMN `add_to_col3` varchar(255) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir, I tried this method also but it's working fine when i remove  end($checkedfileds) line, but for single checkbox it's not working, when i click on the both checkbox only it's adding in the table..i don't know why.

Comment: @Deeksha ah.. I'm sorry I get the `$qry` value reversed in there, it fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `varchar(255)` to each column

```
$input=$_POST['CheckedFileds'];
$checkedfileds = array_map(function($value) { return $value." varchar(255)"; }, $input);
$fields=implode(',',$checkedfileds);
```

Comment: Sir this one is working fine now, but now i need to save first vale in the int(11) and the second value in the varchar(255) format..i changed this line like $checkedfileds = array_map(function($value) { return "ADD"." "."add_to_".$value." varchar(255) NOT NULL"; }, $input);