# How to create a dynamic columns in a table using array values in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, sql, codeigniter

```html
public function addDynFields()
{
    $checkedfileds=$_POST['CheckedFileds'];
    $fields=implode(',',$checkedfileds);
    $dynflds = strtolower($fields);
    $dynclmns = 'add_to'.'_'.$dynflds;
    if($fields == 'Title')
    {
        $this->db->query("ALTER TABLE `pm1asset_dynamic_fields` ADD ".$dynclmns." int(11) NOT NULL");
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->query("ALTER TABLE `pm1asset_dynamic_fields` ADD ".$dynclmns." varchar(255) NOT NULL");
    }
}
```

How to create a dynamic columns in a table using array values in codeigniter. Using First array value we need to create first and using second we need to create a second dynamic column in a table and so on. How to do that can any one please help me. Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: Make it easy and possible to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: I post an answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61009741/12731030

Answer (score 0):

I would not advise that because you also need to give `type, length, default value, null` etc. So, it will be a hectic task. Also, you'll have to check if the table already exists then use Alter table query.

If you must then also take the `type, length` value from the user

### Possible Solution

---

In your function check if the table exists,

```
$query = "SELECT 1 from `Your_Table` LIMIT 1";
//returns false if the table does not exist.
$tableExists = $this->db->query($query);
```

**IF NOT**--
Use CREATE TABLE query--     `//if($tableExists === FALSE)`

```
CREATE TABLE Your_Table(
Column_1 Column_1_Attributes,
Column_2 Column_2_Attributes,
.
. 
)
```

Eg:

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
          id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
          firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
          email VARCHAR(50)
        )";
```

**IF YES--**

Use ALTER TABLE query--

```
ALTER TABLE Your_Table
MODIFY COLUMN new_column new_column_attributes;
```

Eg:

```
$query = "ALTER TABLE MyGuests
          ADD lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL";
```